# Ctrl+j does not open download page at chrome

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium and Java to write a test for Chrome browser. I noticed that

```
   action.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL+ "j").build().perform();
   action.keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
```

does not open download page on Chrome but works on Firefox.

why doesn't it work? and what would work on chrome too?

Comment: I suggest avoiding interaction with Download popup since, on each browser, those are "native components" , and as you expressed, they behave differently.  I think the Marionette project is supposed to eventually resolve this but its still a long way from that in a cross-browser sense.  Instead, just use an Http library to execute a download request on behalf of the download dialog.   The Selenide project has support support functions in this area that I also recommend.

Comment: @djangofan could you post an answer with code and more explanation please

Comment: my answer was nuked by the powers that be...

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps.

a) Press Ctrl-Shift-J (this will launch the chrome://inspector... window)

b) Change focus back on the PeopleSoft Page and then press Ctrl-Shift-J again. This will give the PeopleSoft page info.

If not according to knowledge cannot be customized keyboard shortcuts on chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ->

Open a new Tab and enter URL -> chrome://downloads/

This should solve your problem